# How can I force a program to stay memory resident after it terminates?

Tags: windows-7, performance

I have a program which takes a long time to load every time I launch it and would like to reduce the time it takes to load. I enabled Windows write caching on the C drive, but didn't notice any improvement.

Comment: This question isn't about the memcached program; you should remove the memcached tag.

Comment: Why would *write* caching affect a program's start-up time? What performance monitoring have you performed to make you think that's at all relevant?

Comment: Looking for the same thing. in UNIX, you can set the sticky bit on (executables) binaries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite certain that you can't. You can run the Windows Performance Analyzer Toolkit to see what takes so long and if there's a bottleneck that you can improve. It might simply be slow code from the vendor, in which case there's very little you can do about it.

Comment: MS-DOS supports TSR (Terminate Stay Resident) program. Why wouldn't Windows also support TSR?

Comment: @FrankR. "Automobiles use to support coal-fired boilers. Why do they no longer support this?"

Comment: Your analagy does not equate with my question & comment. There are justified needs for having programs to stay memory resident.

Comment: @FrankR. And what are those reasons? I'm genuinely curious. The memory protection built into all modern OSes guards memory *very* carefully, and this is the way it should be. Once a process exits, all of the memory it had been allocated is immediately inaccessible. If startup times are this much of an issue for you, either leave the application running or increase your server hardware as needed.

Comment: Agreed with EEAA. If the startup time is significant, don't stop it.